# Доступ к приватным полям в классе

Tags: java, code-style

Есть класс, и в нём переменная. Для неё сделан геттер. Как использовать эту переменную в методах этого же класса: напрямую или через геттер?

```
class Box {
    private int x;

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int square() {
        return getX() * getX(); // или this.x * this.x;
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему у вас `Private` и `Public` с заглавной буквы? В яве они пишутся с маленькой.

Comment: изменил. по привычке на шифт шмякаю

Comment: Это не переменная, а поле.

Answer (score 4):

Напрямую. Класс имеет доступ ко всем своим переменным. Можете, конечно, и через геттер, но это глупо.

Comment: это не глупо в случае если геттер не обычный

Comment: Я хотел об этом сказать, но не стал. В данном случае геттер обычный.

Comment: можно подробнее о необычном?

Comment: Если геттер возвращает значение, которое внутри себя ещё сам считает, например у вас есть переменные `rows` и `cols`. Геттер `getCells()` возвратит значение `rows * cols`.

Comment: Для одной переменной тоже можно сделать необычный геттер, который что-то ещё делает. Не знаю, есть ли когда-нибудь смысл возвращать значение одной переменной, изменяя его, но можно в геттер какой-нибудь логгер повесить.

Comment: @padLa внутри гетера может быть какая - то логика, поэтому он необычный

Comment: @ИмяФамилия есть смысл

Answer (score 0):

Надо использовать метод геттера.

Пример необычного геттера:

```
class Custom{
  private int x;

  public int getX(){
    //вызов какого-то бла бла метода
    return x;
  }

  ///..///...
}
```

Comment: вообще это уже не геттер, а метод вычисления квадрата от `x` и во вселенной с минимумом здравого смысла, называться он никак не может getX(), потому что возвращает не `x`, а его квадрат.

Comment: Я об этом и говорил. Вряд ли когда-нибудь что-то подобное где-то будет использоваться. Можно какой-нибудь логгер поставить или что-то подобное разве что.

Comment: @pavlofff если смущал предыдущий ответ, обновил на новый... но смысл от этого не меняется

Comment: @ИмяФамилия хотя внутри класса да, в принципе можно использовать напрямую переменные